# cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, extract

I am trying to use Hotelling test
When I call `hotelling.test(.~Number, bottle.df)`
everything is OK.

However, when I try to do Hotelling test to only one element,

````
```
bottle_elem1<-data.frame(bottle.df$Number,bottle.df$Mn)
hotelling.test(bottle.df.Number, bottle_elem1)
```
````

it gives an error

```
> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame
>Traceback:
>1. data.frame(. ~ Number, bottle.df$Mn)
>2. as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
>3. as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
>4. stop(gettextf("cannot coerce class %s to a data.frame", sQuote(deparse(class(x))[1L])), 
 .     domain = NA)
```

I understand that should do it differently, but don't know how. If I use like previously `.~Number`, there is an error too
What is correct code to do Hotelling test for a column? Maybe I should extract column differently, but don't know how.
bottle is from Hotelling package

```
structure(list(Number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Mn = c(56.1, 
53.8, 58.7, 54.6, 58.6, 56.8), Ba = c(170.7, 166.2, 184.2, 170.5, 
185.2, 180.5), Sr = c(145.1, 143.3, 156.5, 158.1, 161.3, 146.7
), Zr = c(77.4, 71.6, 78.2, 75.3, 83.9, 79.2), Ti = c(267.4, 
270, 286.4, 273.6, 289.9, 274)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(bottle.df))`.

Comment: But this is usual bottle dataframe and I test first two columns